# Codename One Browser Component Redirection

Tags: codenameone

I am using Codename One Browser Component to show a web view that redirects me to the app if I have it installed. The problem is I don't want it to open the app even if it's installed on the device. I want it to stay on the web view and continue instead.
Just for information this problem is only in the IOS version and not the Android version.

Comment: How does it perform the redirect? What sort of link and code does the web browser use? The one thing I can think of is injecting your own JavaScript to replace that URL with a regular URL that won't trigger the app.